# Why is variable scope not available in this example

Tags: javascript

I thought I understood variable scope, but seems like I still need to learn some more.

I have a setup like this:

```
function start() {

    var playerLocation = world001map;
    var doggy = 'wooof!';

    function loadLevel(levelToLoad) {
        levelToLoad();

        loadLevel(playerLocation);
    }
}



function world001map() {
    alert(doggy);
}
```

It seems like I can't access the doggy variable from the world001map function. I thought child functions could always access the variables of their parents.

Why can't I access "doggy" from "world001map" and is there some way to fix the situation?

Comment: Look at your braces - I think your trousers are falling down (i.e. 3 open, 2 closed)

Comment: Also proper indentation would help you out here

Comment: Fixed the braces, sorry that was a mistake I made when stripping the code from unnecessary things.

Comment: You should use http://jsbeautifier.org/ (or a similar tool) to fix the indentation of your javascript code.

Comment: @AndersonGreen thanks for the tip! That seems like a good service! :)

Comment: You are right, however `world001map` is _not_ a "child function" of `start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, doggy is isolated to the start scope.

two ways to fix: pass doggy to world001map:

```
function world001map(doggy)
```

2, make doggy global, set it up outside the start function.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it showed a way to avoid using the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Scope is determined by where a function is *defined* (i.e. the position in the code of the function declaration or function expression), not where it is copied to.

`var playerLocation = world001map` does not give `world001map` access to variables that are scoped to `start`